# IPTables on Debian 8

Tags: linux, security, iptables, anonymity

I am in need of a set of IPTable rules that blocks all requests sent in the clear. I currently have a connection through Tor but when i start up my computer I do not want any connection going in the clear. If someone could give me a set up rules that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o wlan0 -m owner ! --uid-owner debian-tor -j DROP
```